# Can someone explain this SQL query to me? I am not understanding what the buckets are doing or what even is a bucket or bitmask?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Basically the task is to query data to isolate which users have a certain scope of permissions for a project.

```
select  ssm.user_id,s.scope
      from  user_available_scope_sets uass
      join  scope_set_masks ssm
        on  ssm.user_id = uass.user_id
       and  ssm.scope_set_id = uass.scope_set_id
      join  scopes s
        on  case floor(s.bitmask_index / 64)
            when 0 then bucket_0
            when 1 then bucket_1
            when 2 then bucket_2
            when 3 then bucket_3
            when 4 then bucket_4
            when 5 then bucket_5
            else 0
            end & (1 << (s.bitmask_index % 64)) != 0
     where  uass.user_id in (1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [bits manipulations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_manipulation).

Assuming that the `bitmask_index` contains two significant bytes, for example:

```
┌ bit 15 bit 0 ┐
 byte 1  byte 0
┌──────┐┌──────┐
0000000011000101
└────────┘└────┘
    y       x
```

`bitmask_index / 64` is same to `bitmask_index >> 6` (shift bits right to 6 positions) - it is `y` in the example, binary `00000011`, decimal `3`

`bitmask_index % 64` is the masking, same to `bitmask_index & 63` (zero all bits higher then 5) - it is `x` in the example, binary `00000101`, decimal `5`

So, actually, `bitmask_index` field holds two values.

Next, `1 << (s.bitmask_index % 64)` (shift `1` left to the specified value) means "value where x-th and only x-th bit is 1", for our example it is

```
    bit 5 ┐
0000000000100000
```

Finally `value1 & value2 != 0` means "value1 and value2" have common bits.

Obviously that the `bucket_0` - `bucket_5` is the fields in the table (`scope_set_masks` probably?)

And all together:

Depending on the `y` value get `bucket_<n>` field and check is the x-th bit in it `= 1`

You could to play with it using PostgreSQL [bit string types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-bit.html):

```
select
    '0000000011000101'::bit(16) as "Binary value",
    '0000000011000101'::bit(16)::int as "Decimal value",
    (197 / 64)::bit(16) as "197 / 64",
    (197 >> 6)::bit(16) as "197 >> 6",
    (197 % 64)::bit(16) as "197 % 64",
    (197 & 63)::bit(16) as "197 & 63",
    (1 << 5)::bit(16) as "1 << 5",
    (1 << (197 % 64))::bit(16) as "1 << (197 % 64)";

┌─[ RECORD 1 ]────┬──────────────────┐
│ Binary value    │ 0000000011000101 │
│ Decimal value   │ 197              │
│ 197 / 64        │ 0000000000000011 │
│ 197 >> 6        │ 0000000000000011 │
│ 197 % 64        │ 0000000000000101 │
│ 197 & 63        │ 0000000000000101 │
│ 1 << 5          │ 0000000000100000 │
│ 1 << (197 % 64) │ 0000000000100000 │
└─────────────────┴──────────────────┘
```